# Does Windows hotmail or live support openid?

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth, hotmail, windows-live

does hotmail/live support openid? if so , please help me with some sample programs to integrate windows openid in asp.net mvc.
According to this link, microsoft does not support openid:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live_ID#Support_for_OpenID
I din't find any new post or updates about this in recent months. Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer - no. Windows Hotmail (by which I suppose you now mean Outlook) / Live (again by which I suppose you mean Microsoft Accounts) both support OAUTH 2. See **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx**

Comment: OpenID Connect is supported by Microsoft Accounts (aka Windows Live ID, aka Microsoft Passport etc.) as of Feb 2016, please read: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/02/23/for-developers-the-first-use-cases-of-the-converged-microsoft-account-and-azure-active-directory-programming-model-are-now-ga/

Comment: Would you mind revisiting this answer? Both the other answer and the comment seem to indicate that as of late OpenID is available for use, thus making this accepted answer now no longer applicable.

Answer (score 3):

Yes recently, though it doesn't seem well publicised.

It is written up in the "Live Connect APIs" section of MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx

**Update Apr 2015:**
Its available, these days the info is avialable at [One Drive Auth](http://onedrive.github.io/auth/readme.htm)